# Set background color for the whole app. Android, Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to set background color for the whole app. In xml, we use `android:background` tag in fragment or activity.

What analog Compose has? [Surface argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3XJP.png) for theme colorPalette doesn't help. Look for your solutions.

Comment: can you please give more info in your question?

Comment: you can use `background` of `lightColorScheme`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can place your app inside a `Box` with needed background:

```kotlin
setContent {
    YourTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            YourApp()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only apply to one screen and not all screens?

Comment: @David it's gonna apply color for all the screens, if you're using single activity, and all your screens are defined inside `YourApp`, e.g. using Jetpack Navigation

Answer (score 3):

Put a window background color from your theme, which will set the background of your whole app, and also remove the white flicker while the app is loading (which looks quite odd if you have a color background in your app):

**res/values/themes/themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.YourThemeName" 
    parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/purple_700</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I use Splash Activity for remove flicker before onCreate() of MainActivity completed. But thx for pretty solution!

Comment: Glad that it helped! I discovered it recently in a pretty hard way!